# How can I better understand how the data in a dataset converted to a dictionary is organized? (ML)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I started with a 12,000 x 9 dataset of the features I am training with (training_features) and converted this to a dictionary. From which I pulled a single example from a single feature, like so: `dict(training_features)['households']`. This returns a column:

```
0       1064.0
1        839.0
2        286.0
3        464.0
4       1032.0
         ...  
11995    339.0
11996    377.0
11997     18.0
11998    441.0
11999    385.0
Name: households, Length: 12000, dtype: float64
```

Pulling a single example from this feature column

(e.g. `dict(training_features)['households'][0]`)

returns `1064.0`.

Calling the dtype: `dict(training_features)['households'][0].dtype` returns `dtype(float64)`.

So what I'm not understanding is how value in a dictionary (of dtype: float64) can contain another piece of data, also of dtype: float64. Is this a list? What is the thing that is organizing this data? Better worded: What is the object stored in the value of the key-value pair that can itself store more data?

**dict --> `key`: `value`**

**`value` --> `x`**

**`x` --> e.g. `1064.0`**

What sort of object is `x`?

**Edit:** It's a pandas DataFrame.

Comment: dictionaries *do not have dtypes*. To figure out what sort of object `x` is, use `type(x)`. In any event, it looks like your dictionary holds `pandas.Series` objects as values, and this particular series has a `dtype=numpy.float64`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd need to delve deeper into how python stores numbers and such. this is quite simply put that python stores pretty much EVERYTHING as objects (or at the least pointers to objects stored in memory) this includes numbers.

So with your example it is storing a class object of `float64` with the value of `1064.0`.

Also let it be known that `float64` is [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html)'s equivalent to python's [float](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#float).

For more explanation on how python stores numbers see [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_numbers.htm)

As the case with [dicts](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) they can have any hashable object as a `key` and any object as a value.

So pretty much anything can be in the value position of a dict whereas the key position needs to be hashable this way python can determine indexing and such on the key field to differentiate keys. This goes deeper than I am explaining but should be a good explanation for this case.

Answer (score 0):

x can be of (almost?) any valid type, here a scalar (int, float...) but it could also be a list, a set, a tuple...
Here your value 1064.0 is of type float64, a scalar (a "constant") and is what is pointed to by the key (of value) 0, as in the simple dictionary {0:1024.0}
You could have several values with lists as in {0:[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], 1:[4.0]}